# Why JQuery function moves elements on their own

Tags: jquery, html, css

I do not understand why `mouseleave()` is moving elements. The original width value of `.card` is `25%` and on `mouseleave()` it is still `25%`. When mousing over the cards, the cards are moving.
HTML

```
 <div id="section">
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card"></div>
     <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
       <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 body {
  background: #20262E;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}
.card-container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
.card {
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 25px 10px;
}
```

Jquery

```
$('.card').click(function() {
    $('.card').not($(this)).animate({'width':'10%'}, 400);
    $(this).animate({'width':'70%'}, 400);
    $(this).addClass('show-text');
});
$('.card').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.card').animate({'width':'25%'}, 400);
});
```

EDIT: Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f4hkcjem/5/

Comment: Your fiddle animates to `{'width':'100%'}` in the mouseleave handler, contrary to what you have shown here.

Comment: i think it is because you are telling to jquery to do it and that shy is moving , when you should tell it to do it if is not 25%

Comment: You mean the glitchy animation, when you don't click on the element, just hover/leave element make the width change for a moment, right?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8darbf0m/11/ I tried checking if one of the cards is in a certain state before always triggering the animate back to 25%

Comment: `$('.card').click(function() {
            $('.card').not($(this)).animate({'width':'10%'}, 400);
            $(this).animate({'width':'70%'}, 400);
            $(this).addClass('show-text');
        });
        $('.card').mouseleave(function() {
            $('.card').css({'width':'25%'}, 400); //remove animation 
        });`
    
 
i think this may help you but here i have removed the animation on mouse-leave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should add mouseout fuction. sometimes mouseleave not working properly

**Jquery**

```
$('.card').click(function(){
    $('.card').not($(this)).animate({'width':'10%'}, 400);
    $(this).animate({'width':'70%'}, 400);
    $(this).addClass('show-text');

});
$('body').on( 'mouseout','.card.show-text',function(){
      $('.card').animate({'width':'25%'}, 400);
       $(this).removeClass('show-text');
 });
```

Comment: Yep, that fixes it. Thank you very much sir. I will restrain myself from using mouseout ever again :))